# Why must I define IEnumerator<T>.Current & IEnumerator.Current, and what does that achieve?

Tags: c#

When implementing IEnumerable & IEnumerator on a class I was writing during training, I noticed that I was required to specify two implementations for the property "Current".

```
public class PeopleEnumerator : IEnumerator<Person>
{
    People people; // my collection I'm enumerating (just a wrapped array).
    int index; // my index to keep track of where in the collection I am.

    ...

    //implementation for Person
    public Person Current { get { return people[index]; } }

    //implementation for object
    object Enumerator.Current { get { return people[index]; } }
}
```

I roughly understand that I'm implementing some non-generic version of IEnumerator and a "Current" property for it, however I don't understand the following things:

- Why am I allowed to overload by return type here? Presumably it has something to do with the explicit IEnumerator.Current; however the reasons are opaque to me.
- Why can "object IEnumerator.Current" not be specified as "public"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one reason you must implement two different interfaces: backwards compatibility. C# 1.0 did not have generics.
In C# 2.0, we got `IEnumerator<T>` which extends the 1.0 `IEnumerator`.

> - Why am I allowed to overload by return type here? Presumably it has something to do with the explicit IEnumerator.Current; however the reasons are opaque to me.

You **cannot** overload methods or properties by return type only; that's why one of them must be an explicit implementation.

> - Why can "object IEnumerator.Current" not be specified as "public"?

Same reason. It has to be an explicit implementation. An explicit implementation cannot have a visibility modifier as a rule. It cannot possibly have any other visibility. `IEnumerator.Current` can only be called through an instance of the `IEnumerator` interface.

Comment: That confirms a lot of my suspicions about the problem, thanks! Still a bit confused about explicit definitions of properties / methods, might have to look at the MSIL to really understand what is happening.